# Why Kotlin Android APP gets java.lang.VerifyError KotlinNamesAnnotationIntrospector on KitKat

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-4.4-kitkat

I'm using Android Studio 3.2.1 on Ubuntu 16.04 with Kotlin plug-in 1.3.11. If I deploy my app with Android Studio to a virtual device with KitKat (API 19), the app is started but immediately crashes. The OS says "Unfortunately,  has stopped. I see in the debugger console the following exception:

```
W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x9ccbbb20)
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: info.diethealth.app, PID: 2583
    java.lang.VerifyError: com/fasterxml/jackson/module/kotlin/KotlinNamesAnnotationIntrospector
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.KotlinModule.setupModule(KotlinModule.kt:40)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.registerModule(ObjectMapper.java:722)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.ExtensionsKt.registerKotlinModule(Extensions.kt:15)
        at info.diethealth.app.business.dagger.DietHealthApiModule.provideObjectMapper(DietHealthApiModule.kt:20)
        at info.diethealth.app.business.dagger.DietHealthApiModule_ProvideObjectMapperFactory.get(DietHealthApiModule_ProvideObjectMapperFactory.java:23)
        at info.diethealth.app.business.dagger.DietHealthApiModule_ProvideObjectMapperFactory.get(DietHealthApiModule_ProvideObjectMapperFactory.java:8)
        at dagger.internal.DoubleCheck.get(DoubleCheck.java:47)
        at info.diethealth.app.business.dagger.DietHealthApiModule_ProvidesRetrofitFactory.get(DietHealthApiModule_ProvidesRetrofitFactory.java:37)
        at info.diethealth.app.business.dagger.DietHealthApiModule_ProvidesRetrofitFactory.get(DietHealthApiModule_ProvidesRetrofitFactory.java:11)
        at dagger.internal.DoubleCheck.get(DoubleCheck.java:47)
        at info.diethealth.app.business.dagger.DietHealthApiModule_ProvidesDietHealthApiFactory.get(DietHealthApiModule_ProvidesDietHealthApiFactory.java:31)
        at info.diethealth.app.business.dagger.DietHealthApiModule_ProvidesDietHealthApiFactory.get(DietHealthApiModule_ProvidesDietHealthApiFactory.java:10)
        at dagger.internal.DoubleCheck.get(DoubleCheck.java:47)
        at info.diethealth.app.business.dagger.DietHealthServicesModule_ProvidesRecipeDescriptionServiceFactory.get(DietHealthServicesModule_ProvidesRecipeDescriptionServiceFactory.java:69)
        at info.diethealth.app.business.dagger.DietHealthServicesModule_ProvidesRecipeDescriptionServiceFactory.get(DietHealthServicesModule_ProvidesRecipeDescriptionServiceFactory.java:16)
        at dagger.internal.DoubleCheck.get(DoubleCheck.java:47)
        at info.diethealth.app.components.main.MainActivity_MembersInjector.injectMembers(MainActivity_MembersInjector.java:31)
        at info.diethealth.app.components.main.MainActivity_MembersInjector.injectMembers(MainActivity_MembersInjector.java:8)
        at info.diethealth.app.business.dagger.DaggerDietHealthComponent.inject(DaggerDietHealthComponent.java:242)
        at info.diethealth.app.components.main.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:50)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

There is no problem with Lollipop (5.0, 5.1) or Marshmallow (6.0).